# How to update in Mongoose query Object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to change the status to Y for particular comment if i click approved button in UI, My document structure is below.

```
     {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1fd0ffef39ff11ae353d10"),
    "file_name" : "Profile",
    "file_type" : "docx",
    "created_date" : ISODate("2017-11-28T10:29:10.373Z"),
    "updated_date" : ISODate("2017-11-28T12:39:32.148Z"),

    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "created_date" : ISODate("2017-11-28T13:23:51.472Z"),
            "status" : "N",
            "comment_text" : "Yes...",
            "username" : "Vishnu"
        }, 
        {
            "created_date" : ISODate("2017-11-28T13:24:15.938Z"),
            "status" : "N",
            "comment_text" : "Yes...",
            "username" : "Vishnu"
        }, 
        {
            "created_date" : ISODate("2017-11-28T13:28:44.455Z"),
            "status" : "N",
            "comment_text" : "fsdfdsf",
            "username" : "T"
        }, 
        {
            "created_date" : ISODate("2017-11-28T13:29:22.132Z"),
            "status" : "N",
            "comment_text" : "fdsfsdf",
            "username" : "dasdas"
        }, 
        {
            "created_date" : ISODate("2017-11-28T13:29:46.247Z"),
            "status" : "N",
            "comment_text" : "fdgdfgfd",
            "username" : "Vishnu T"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried some query which was already in stackover flow like

```
 mongo.filemanager.update(
            { "_id": req.body.id, "comments.comment_text": req.body.comments },
            { "$set": { "comments.$.status": 'Y' } }
        )
```

But status value is not get changing. am using mongoose here.

Kindly help me in this issue.. Thanks In advance

**Updated**

```
mongo.filemanager.findOneAndUpdate(
        { "_id": req.body.id, "comments.comment_text": req.body.comments },
        {
           "$set": { "comments.$.status": 'Y' } 
        },
        function(err,doc) {
                if (err) throw err
                console.log("Updated Commentstatus")
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your response... I tried but its not working

Comment: Is update query ll work in mongoose?

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't work? Are you looking at update result?

Comment: Yes I have added $ .. But my status is not changing

Comment: BTW does `req.body.comments` contain `comments.comment_text`? The name suggests that it contains array of comments or sth. Than the query would not find that document to be updated.

Comment: Yes my req.body.comments value...I have update my original document kindly check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the syntax of update in mongoose.

**`Model.update(conditions, update, options, callback);`**

So,

`$set` should be the second paramter,

try

```
mongo.filemanager.update({ "_id": req.body.id, "comments.comment_text": req.body.comments  },{ "$set": { "comments.status": 'Y' } })
```

[Mongoose official Documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html)

You can also use `findOneAndUpdate`,

```
mongo.filemanager.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "_id": req.body.id, "comments.comment_text": req.body.comments },
    {
       "$set": { "comments.status": 'Y' } 
    },
    function(err,doc) {

    }
);
```

Comment: Your request gonna update every `status` in the `comments` array.

Comment: I have use $set as second parameter only... but my comment status is not get changing

Comment: @Vishnu, you need to compare comment text also?

Comment: Thank you so much ...I have tried your second choice  with $ which was mentioned by Grégory NEUT its working perfect...:)

Comment: Glad to help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've made an example that look like your case, interesting.

[image]

---

You can simulate mongodb terminal online in [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb_terminal_online.php) for free

Comment: Thank you ...I ll try again

Comment: Thank you so Much Its working ... I have used Sravan ans findOneAndUpdate with $ ...not its perfect thank you so much ... :)